# Proof that $\mathbf{E}\bigl[Y|\mathcal{F}_t\bigr]$ is a martingale

Tags: probability-theory

> *Exercise :* Let $Y$ be a random variable with $\mathbf{E}\bigl[|Y|\bigr] < \infty$ and let $\mathbb{F}$ be a filtration as well as
>   \begin{equation*}
>   X_t := \mathbf{E}\bigl[Y | \mathcal{F}_t\bigr]
> \end{equation*}
>   for all $t \in I$. Show that $X$ is an $\mathbb{F}$-martingale.

*Solution:* $X_t$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable for any $t\in I$, so it is adapted to $\mathbb{F}$. Also

\begin{equation*}
  \mathbf{E}\bigl[|X_t|\bigr] = \mathbf{E}\bigl[|\mathbf{E}[Y|\mathcal{F}_t]|\bigr] \overset{\triangle-\text{ineq.}}{\leq} \mathbf{E}\Bigl[\mathbf{E}\bigl[|Y|\big|\mathcal{F}_t\bigr]\Bigr] = \mathbf{E}\bigl[|Y|\bigr] < \infty \, .
\end{equation*}
Then for $t,s \in I$ with $t> s$ we get
\begin{equation*}
  \mathbf{E}[X_t|\mathcal{F}_s] = \mathbf{E}\bigl[\mathbf{E}[Y|\mathcal{F}_t]|\mathcal{F}_s\bigr] \overset{\text{tower-prop.}}{=} \mathbf{E}[Y|\mathcal{F}_s] = X_s\, . \square
\end{equation*}

Comment: Could you at least post your solution?

Comment: Note that $\overset{\triangle-\text{ineq.}}{=}$ should read $\overset{\triangle-\text{ineq.}}{\leq}$.

Comment: of course, I meant it that way.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is fine.

You may want to show the tower proposition to be more complete.

Note that in this case the martingale is said to be closed by $Y$